# Unexpected results when calling resize() on an STL vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers

In the following code, if I call v.resize(n), the program will print out **0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0**, which is not what I wanted to see. However, if I comment the line containing v.resize(n) out, it will print out **0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**, which is what I wanted to see. Why is this the case? What's wrong with my logic here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc , char ** argv )
{
    int n = 10;
    vector<int> v;
    v.resize(n);

    for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you're confused about the contents of a container, don't assume you know its size. Instead of looping from `0` to `n` to display the contents, use an iterator and loop from `begin()` to `end()`.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `.reserve` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v.push_back(i)` increases the size of the vector `v` by 1 with `i` being the value of the last element in that vector. That is why the 10 zeros are retained at the start (i.e. front) of the vector.

You should write `v[i] = i` instead.

Whatever you do, don't drop the line `v.resize(n);` and retain your `push_back` as it's suboptimal to piecewise resize a vector - due to memory reallocation. (Although a good `stl` will have optimisations for such programming it's good practice not to rely on that).

Comment: Well, replacing `resize`with `reserve`would also be an option, and probably that would result in the behavior the OP expected.

Comment: @Hulk: Agreed: it would do if, of course, he dropped the `resize1`; and memory reallocation will not occur.

Answer (score 7):

`resize` ensures the vector contains exactly `n` elements, while `push_back` appends items to the `vector`, so the nubmers are added after zeros that occupy the vector after resizing. You can see it if you print all the numbers in the vector (`< v.size()`) instead of just first `n`.

Method that behaves as you seem to have expected is `reserve()`:

> *Effects:* A directive that informs a vector of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation accordingly. After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of
>   `capacity()` otherwise. Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of `reserve()`. If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable type, there are no effects. (`§23.3.6.3/2`)

Answer (score 4):

[`vector.resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

> Resizes the container so that it contains n elements.

You're resizing it to `n` (10). So now it has ten 0's in it. Then you add ten *more* numbers (0 to 9) to the end of the list (via [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)).  Finally, you print out only the first `n` (10) which are still all zero.

Your program is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: I see. So I must assign values using the  [] operator, right?

Comment: @takwing: Yes, Or else use `reserve()` which only reserves memory to be used when the vector resizes.

Comment: @tawking If you want to *replace* the zeros you've already placed into the vector, yes.